# Make a viewcontroller a splitviewcontroller

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am creating an ipad application which first shows the login screen and after that i need to show the master/detail format on the navigated page.
Previuosly i didnt have much time to do the research so i created those views manually using orientation and hiding/showing of the views placed on the viewcontroller.

Is there any way to make the viewcontroller a splitviewcontroller.

Please advise.

THanks,

Comment: no response till now...got to create it manually again!!